# How to get parent link of fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How to get parent window URL inside a child window of fancy box

Comment: can you make your question more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to accessing the containing document's URL from an iframe, try:

```
window.top.location.href
```